# What database to use on a web project deployed on live site using IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I just finished creating a webpage with sign-up fields, which asks some informations from people.  I  used Visual Studio2012 C#.net on MVC 4 Framework.  In making the database to hold the entries, I used SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database. The project work well on my local computer.  I have also published the project on IIS7 and the project still responded well.  To further test this project, I had up on a Test Site and the sign up entries still gets entered into the database.  However, when I deployed the project on the live site, the sign-up form doesn't work anymore.  As I enter the details on the fields and press the submit button, this message comes out:

> *"Server Error in '/' Application. Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1914,File name = C:\inetpub\wwwroot.... and so on"*

I've made some researching and found out that localdb isn't made to work with IIS so perhaps I might switch to another SQL database.  What I have right now is the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but I don't really know how will I be able to connect my project to the database table once I've made it.  I tried looking for tutorials but most examples were still using the localdb.  But there is this SQL Server Express Database.  Is there any difference between the two?

I am a newbie in web development and I hadn't really been working with databases or with servers and I'm kind'a lost right now. Does anyone know any tutorials I can refer to? or does anyone know any solution or any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: I suggest you go for Sql Server Express Edition. Its free and if you used EF code first for your initial db then the only things you need to change are: connection string (Data Source=.;Integrated Security=true) + create a login with the same name as the ThreadPool name your application is running in on IIS. 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5' for example.

Comment: Have you considered reading some tutorials? I mean, yo uask for them but hey, they are all over the place. Google, asp.net (the website) has tons of them, so asking for them is like stading in a forest and asking where the trees are. Just got and read them.

Comment: You should contact the hosting company and ask them what kind of databases they support? My hosting company supports only MySQL databases, so I had to integrate MySQL database with my ASP.net MVC app.

Comment: neo112, does this mean that SQL Server Management cannot be used like the SQL Server Express? I was just confused after reading out from some forums that the two has no difference.  Anyway, regarding that, I've already made a database folder and table in my management studio and have already done the APPPOOL you said in IIS before. I thought I just don't know how to call the database from the management studio but with what you said, perhaps I'm just missing another important application which is the SQL express. Did I get it right?

Comment: TomTom, yeah like I said I'm lost, lost in the forest looking for a certain tree not where the trees are.  I've been searching but I just failed to find what I needed.  I don't think there's anything wrong asking for directions. I'm still searching through google right now.

Comment: badaBoom now that you mentioned it that just made me think.  Thanks I'd consider doing that now.